# What happened to all of the clones after the clone wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, clones

So once Star Wars episode IV: A New Hope starts, the Clone Wars are over, but what is the fate of the clones? Are the stormtroopers in episodes IV, V and VI leftover clone troopers? Did the Kamino cloners keep making clones for the republic/empire after the clone wars ended? When did the empire start hiring actual real people (and not just using clones) for their armies?

Comment: Duplicate, I think.

Comment: I searched and couldn't find an answer to my specific question, can you link me the duplicate please?

Comment: You've got about three questions here, and I'm pretty sure they're all dupes of something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clones, being modified to age at twice the normal rate, mostly retired by the time of the original trilogy.

They were the equivalent of a ~60 year old by A New Hope, having aged 32 real years (the time between the Invasion of Naboo and the Battle of Yavin), but themselves aging as though 64 had passed.

The Empire replaced the Clone Troopers with standard enlisted Stormtroopers.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to watch Star Wars Rebels now! :)

Comment: @fiend No problem. Rebels and Clone Wars are both official canon, by the way.